# Como detectar scroll no modal bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3

Segue meu código CSS:

```
.modal-body {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Segue código JS:

```
$('.modal-body').on('scroll', function () {
    console.log('scroll y');
});
```

Código JS não está funcionando, alguma solução ?

Comment: Essa modal ja vem inclusa na página desde o começo ou você coloca o elemento dela depois do carregamento ?

Comment: @AnthraxisBR encontrei a solução, veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução:

```
$('#minhaModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $('.modal-body').on('scroll', function() {
    console.log('scroll y');
  });
})
```

Comment: Nossa, que estranho funcionar assim, usar um evento pra disparar outro evento, mas o importante é funcionar kk testa colocando $(document).on('scroll','.modal-body',function(  pra ver se funciona também só de teste, sem colocar o 'shown.bs.modal' , ai acho que consegue com um disparo só

Comment: Testei o código: `$(document).on('scroll', '.modal-body', function () {console.log("scroll y");});` não funcionou  :/, deveria funcionar. Tem algo secreto que eu não vejo.